# Which is more correct in English?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I want to describe the people living in Germany, not only those who carry German citizenship but even migrants. 
Which is better to describe this: 
-The German People.
-The people of Germany.
and why?
Many thanks,

Comment: "Residents" is the term commonly used in the US to refer to people residing in a country, be they citizens, legal aliens, or illegal (ie, "undocumented) aliens.  "Legal residents" excludes the "illegal aliens".  The term is commonly taken to exclude those who are "just visiting", but is fairly vague with regard to those who have, eg, overstayed a tourist visa.

Comment: "People living in Germany" would be a clear way of referring to people living in Germany.

Comment: This is better asked on a law-related SE. Grammar and usage may only confound and not help much in such cases. Good Luck.

Comment: What about 'Germans'

Answer (score 0):

None of them seems to be correct considering your description. Both of them have very different meanings than what you want to refer. You can go simple and say `people in Germany`.

For instance, `People in Germany are very nice`. Everyone who listens this sentence would understand exactly what you just wanted to refer.